# Is it possible to force value in property setter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

What I want is to override UINavigationBar tintColor setter and force default color to it. Bellow is my code (which of course fails). Is there a way to make it work?

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)setTintColor:(UIColor *)tint {
self.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm using `property` as a generic term here, in your example it's a stand-in for `tintColor`)

I don't think you can use the `self.property =` syntax for assignment inside a `setProperty:` method. `self.property` is just an alias for `[self setProperty:<value>]` and it will recursively call itself.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
- (void)setProperty:(id)pProperty {
     [property autorelease];

     property = [pProperty retain];
}
```

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to do will work, but the preceding is a start.

Comment: Thank you for informative answer! I understand the recursive problem of my code and that's why I was interested if there's another way. As for my particular problem I've found another way to force default tint color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a default color of a NavigationBar, why don't you set the tint color in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear of your view controller??

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor (color you want)];
```

Comment: Basically, because I have many view controllers and I would like to have only one place where I can set such property for all the navigation bars. Also that would be too easy! :)